# Hausdorff Dimension of a manifold of dimension n?

Tags: analysis, geometry, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Let's say that $M$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension $n$. (This includes that $M$ is nonempty and second countable, so that it can be embedded into some Euclidean space, and is thus metrizable.)

Is it well-defined to say that $M$ has Hausdorff dimension $n$ even though it is only a metrizable topological space?  I.e. do we have that whenever two metric spaces are homeomorphic, then they have the same Hausdorff dimension?

Is it true?

Comment: I don't know about Hausdorff dimension, but the dimension of a manifold (differentiable or not) is well defined -- manifolds of different dimension have (locally) different homotopy groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hausdorff dimension is not a topological invariant.
But saying that $M$ is a differentiable manifold gives you more than just a homeomorphic embedding.  The charts determine a metric on each patch, in which the patch has Hausdorff dimension $n$.  And diffeomorphisms are bi-Lipschitz, so they preserve Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: Do you have an example to show it is not a topological invariant?

Comment: @Jeff I think you can just take $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$, which is homeomorphic under the identity with Euclidean space, but has Hausdorff dimension $2$.