# Are these definitions of dimension for a real algebraic variety all equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I would like to believe that the following notions of dimension are all equivalent for an a real algebraic variety in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. [Lower Minkowski dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension)
2. [Upper Minkowski dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension)
3. [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension)
4. [real dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety#Real_dimension)

(I realize that the [algebraic dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety) might be strictly larger.)

Is this true? Assuming so, any references to the literature that would be appropriate to cite for this fact would be appreciated.

I know that real algebraic varieties (and even semi-algebraic sets) are [triangulable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)). Is that already enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the algebraic dimension is potentially *bigger*, not potentially smaller. Think about $V(x^2+y^2)$, for instance - this is algebraic dimension 1 but real dimension zero.

Second, yes, these are all equivalent for real varieties (where we mean the set of solutions to a system of polynomial equations in $\Bbb R^n$). Any such variety is a semi-algebraic set, which admits a stratification in to a finite union of locally closed submanifolds (see for instance corollary 3.8 in Michel Coste's [*Introduction to Semialgebraic Geometry*](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf)). Since all three take finite unions to maximums, it suffices to show the claim for a smoothly semialgebraically-embedded copy of $(0,1)^d\subset\Bbb R^n$.

This immediately shows that the definition of 4 is $d$. For Hausdorff dimension, the fact the embedding is a diffeomorphism gives [dimension $d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931628/hausdorff-dimension-of-a-manifold-of-dimension-n). The upper box dimension is also $d$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890260/minkowski-dimension-of-the-subset). Since the Hausdorff dimension is at most the lower box dimension is at most the upper box dimension, this shows that all three quantities are $d$.

Comment: If we define the algebraic dimension of $V\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be $\dim \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]/ I(V)$, then the algebraic dimension is the same as the real dimension, is this true? I think it is true, but don't have a proof.

Comment: @Pew yes, since you'll have a smooth point in each component. Comments are probably too small of a space to explain fully, though.

Comment: thank you. Do you know a reference for this？

Comment: @Pew Not off the top of my head. It's not so difficult to prove, though - if you're looking to understand why this happens, I might suggest asking a question on it. (Comments are not great for explaining in - short character limits.)

Comment: ok, I will ask. So you are basically saying, given an algebraic set (real), then every irreducible component of it must have a smooth point, right?