# Algebraic dimension of complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading second chapter of *Faisceaux Perverse* by BBD. I have few questions in the following paragraph:

> Let $X(\Bbb C)$ be complex points of separated scheme of finite type over complex number $C$,provided with usual topology. Each stratification of $X$ has a refinement which is Whitney stratification. Define perversity function as $P(S) = p(2 \operatorname{alg} S) = p(\operatorname{top} S)$ where $\operatorname{alg}$ is the algebraic dimension of $S$ and $p$ is decreasing function from even integers to integers.

I have the following questions:

1. Why we have taken the usual topology and not the Zariski topology?
2. What are algebraic and topological dimension?
3. Why we are taking twice the algebraic dimension?

Comment: One questions at a time? What have you tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde this is a few very closely related questions about a single passage - I think there's a case to be made for packaging them up together.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, this makes sense. However, a little bit more effort from the OP would be desirable. For example, looking up something yourself for $2.$ can be expected. It is often seen critical here to give an answer to "no effort questions", see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Answer (score 1):

1. The goal is essentially to generalize intersection homology for manifolds, so taking the usual topology is the appropriate thing to do here.
2. Algebraic dimension is the dimension you know from algebraic geometry: Krull dimension of a variety/scheme/etc. Topological dimension is any of a number of dimensions associated to a variety, [all of which are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410586/are-these-definitions-of-dimension-for-a-real-algebraic-variety-all-equivalent/4410616#4410616). For instance, one way to explain this is that every algebraic variety over $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$ has a Whitney stratification ([ref Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_conditions)), and the maximum dimension of a piece of this stratification is the topological dimension.
3. For varieties over $\Bbb C$, the topological dimension is twice the algebraic dimension. It's easiest to observe this by looking at $\Bbb A^n_{\Bbb C}$: the $\Bbb C$-points are $\Bbb C^n$, which has topological dimension $2n$, since topologically this is $\Bbb R^{2n}$, while $\Bbb A^n_{\Bbb C}$ has algebraic dimension $n$.